Sqlite's [Ignore] not working with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm's [ObservableProperty]
I have a field in my Model that I want to [Ignore] during SqliteConnection.CreateTable<myModel>  but I also use the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm [ObservableProperty] and this is causing an error for the [Ignore].

Attribute 'attribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
valid on 'type' declarations only.

[ObservableProperty]
[Ignore]
private Image imgStream;

How can I have this field ignored at the time of table creation but still use the CTKM ObservableObject?

[Ignore] is expecting a property not a field, seems there is an old issue on that: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/1128

What if you specifically target the property by applying [property: Ignore] to private Image imgStream;?  This works for [JsonPropertyNameAttribute] as shown in this answer by Andrew KeepCoding to How to combine [JsonPropertyName] and [ObservableProperty] on the same member? so it might work for SQLite.Ignore as well.

See also Allow custom property attributes for [ObservableProperty] #413 which was closed as implemented on Sep 28, 2022.

Does this answer your question? Use [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement] from SQLite in .NET MAUI with [ObservablePropertys]

@Cfun - property: is part of the C# syntax, it's the global_attribute_target_specifier from 22.3 Attribute specification.  The fact that the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm source generators apply [property: Ignore] on an [ObservableProperty] field to the auto-generated property was implemented in pull Enable explicit attribute forwarding for [ObservableProperty] #449.

@dbc Thanks a lot very helpful to understand ths bits.
